# opscenter Disks stats not available

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

hi everybody im using OpsCenter 5.2.0  and agent connected to opscenter 
bout no Disks in  Dashboard I have error on  datastax-agent log

ERROR [os-metrics-7] 2015-08-23 21:00:37,095 Short os-stats collector failed: Process failed: df --print-type --no-sync --block-size=1G --local

Comment: Try running the command directly on your C* node `df --print-type --no-sync --block-size=1G --local`. Are you on OSX?

Comment: Filesystem     Type     1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4           243    14       217   6% /
none           tmpfs            1     0         1   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev           devtmpfs        16     1        16   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs            4     1         4   1% /run
none           tmpfs            1     0         1   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs           16     1        16   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs            1     1         1   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb       ext4           274    92       169  36% /media/HardData  above is the  result

Comment: Try running it as your cassandra user

Comment: many thanks for you reply bout  i get Permission denied
when run with user cassandra

Comment: Is cassandra in sudoers?